# Elasticsearch suggestion scoring not working with fuzzy search

Tags: elasticsearch

When next elasticsearch query getting data for autocomplete recieved data is not relevant and scoring not working

```
GET quick_search/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "name-suggest": {
      "text": "Clic",
      "completion": {
          "field": "Name",
          "size": 25,
          "skip_duplicates": true,
          "fuzzy" : {
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "prefix_length": 1,
              "min_length": 4,
              "unicode_aware": true
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query for search is "Clic" but in search results fuzzy search found not maximum relevant data. How can I boost my results for maximum relevancy for words as "CLIC7000" cause for my query it more relative than "CLI36"

```
{
  "took" : 706,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 15,
    "successful" : 15,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "name-suggest" : [
      {
        "text" : "Clic",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 4,
        "options" : [
          {
            "text" : "CLI36",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "330719",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "330719",
              "Name" : "CLI36"
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "CLI361511B001",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "330717",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "330717",
              "Name" : "CLI361511B001"
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "CLI42C6385B001",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "185340",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "185340",
              "Name" : "CLI42C6385B001"
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "CLI42PM",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "185345",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "185345",
              "Name" : "CLI42PM",
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "CLI42PM6389B001",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "185343",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "185343",
              "Name" : "CLI42PM6389B001"
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "CLI441",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "233554",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "233554",
              "Name" : "CLI441"
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "CLI451BK",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "185334",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "185334",
              "Name" : "CLI451BK"
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "CLI451BK6523B001",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "185332",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "185332",
              "Name" : "CLI451BK6523B001"
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "CLI451C",
            "_index" : "quick_search",
            "_type" : "quick_search",
            "_id" : "185331",
            "_score" : 3.0,
            "_source" : {
              "ID" : "185331",
              "Name" : "CLI451C"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```